# Single word for cast and crew of a movie

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

What do you call a person that works for a movie?
*Celebrity* comes close, but is that all?

I am making a list of people (each and everyone) that worked for a movie. Wondering what the name of that list should be!

Comment: The crew isn't famous; that's the job of the cast. So _celebrity_ doesn't come close to what you asked. Unless you mean something else in a particular context, in which case you'd hafta explain the context.

Answer (score 3):

I would call that person a [cineast](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cineaste) or "cineaste," a "[movie worker"](http://www.highbeam.com/doc/1G1-155307278.html), a ["movie professional"](http://www.ohio.com/news/movie-professionals-teach-their-skills-to-tri-c-class-1.463199), or -- more commonly -- a "participant to a movie."

> **[cineast](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cineast)**: any person, esp. a director or producer, associated professionally with filmmaking.

Comment: Wiktionary: A person in the filmmaking industry. That is what I was looking for! Thanks man.

Comment: I am not sure how I could ever bring myself to use a word that no one would understand, I potentially couldn't pronounce right, and would be much easier conveyed in other terms.  Not feeling this one.

Comment: Wait did you sneak a French word in on us!  Should I know this word? (learning French)

Comment: Is there a better word then? Rotten Tomatoes uses celebrity for anyone in a movie. But in reality, only so many are celebrities in a movie.

Comment: That's not a single word though.

Comment: @Alexander Then how about two words? Movie worker. http://www.highbeam.com/doc/1G1-155307278.html

Comment: "In the movie" usually designates just those that were viewed on film, not the behind the scenes crew.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd Correct

Answer (score 2):

Everyone who is in a movie or works on the movie should be on the credits.  So if we want to list everyone that was involved in a film, I would say they were **credited**.

Also it seems like the term is fairly common ([google](https://www.google.com/search?q=object%20you%20can%20touch%20but%20not%20see&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=sb#channel=sb&q=credited%20on%20a%20movie&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial)).

Comment: Not really. You may work on a movie without being credited for whatever reason, and vice versa. The concepts should correlate, naturally, but they are distinct.

Comment: @Zano I know there are some union rules on credits and stuff like that but if you had any major impact on a film you are in the credits.  There are caterers and florists listed in movie credits.  I am in no way imposing that this is an all inclusive list of everyone but it conveys cast and crew.

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about. Being in the credits and being a participant in making a film are two distinct concepts with a high level of correlation. Being "credited" means that your name is in the credits, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @Zano  OK.  I highly disagree with that.  You are saying they put random people in the credits?

Comment: Let me give you an example: Bruce Willis was not credited for his role in Four Rooms, but he was still an actor in that movie. Likewise, Ashton Kutcher was not credited for Cheaper by the Dozen. These things happens, sometimes by mistake, sometimes deliberately. The opposite happens as well, mostly by mistake, but also deliberately; Alan Smithee springs to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Old plays simply credited "The Company."

Comment: Hmmm.. 2 words. But that could be mistaken for the studio too.

Comment: @Alexander Not, the Company is no more two words than the crew or the cast is two words: because when you speak of nouns, you customarily use some sort of determiner in front of them in English, and the article is not part of the term.  The capitalization, though, changes everything, and has a special meaning handed down to us from thespian traditions of old.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for everyone involved in the creation of that movie, so say just that, *involved*. It's a single word. And it nicely sidesteps the issue of whether they were credited.